# Clear, Move, Animate a Point on libigl Viewer?

Tags: ros, eigen3, libigl

I would like to use the libigl viewer to display a 3d model and a point. The 3d model will remain unchanged at all time, but the point will move around. My current approach is basically:

1. load the 3d model and point
2. viewer.data().clear() to clear the viewer
3. go to step 1 again

However, it's slow especially when the 3d model has a lot of vertices because it needs reload everything after each clear. Preferably, I want to either clear only that single point or move that point to a new coordinate. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`viewer.data().set_points(...)` will clear just the point-related data and replace it with the input positions and color(s). The mesh will not be modified or cleared. So, no need to call `viewer.data().clear()` when just changing the points.

Here's a minimalish example based on the libigl-example-project:

```
#include <igl/opengl/glfw/Viewer.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // Inline mesh of a cube
  const Eigen::MatrixXd V= (Eigen::MatrixXd(8,3)<< -1.0,-1.0,-1.0, -1.0,-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0,-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,-1.0,-1.0, 1.0,-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0).finished();
  const Eigen::MatrixXi F = (Eigen::MatrixXi(12,3)<< 1,7,5, 1,3,7, 1,4,3, 1,2,4, 3,8,7, 3,4,8, 5,7,8, 5,8,6, 1,5,6, 1,6,2, 2,6,8, 2,8,4).finished().array()-1;
  igl::opengl::glfw::Viewer viewer;
  // Set mesh
  viewer.data().set_mesh(V, F);
  viewer.data().set_face_based(true);
  viewer.core().is_animating = true;
  // Initialize point
  Eigen::MatrixXd P = (Eigen::MatrixXd(1,3)<<1.42,0,0).finished();
  // function will be  called before every draw
  viewer.callback_pre_draw = [&](igl::opengl::glfw::Viewer & )->bool
  {
    // Create orbiting animation
    P = (1.42*(P+Eigen::RowVector3d(P(1),-P(0),P(2))*0.1).normalized()).eval();
    // update point location. no .clear() necessary
    viewer.data().set_points(P,Eigen::RowVector3d(1,1,1));
    return false;
  };
  viewer.launch();
}
```

[image: animation of point in libigl viewer]

Comment: Thanks! The set_points function works great, but now I have to group all the points together and "set" them all at once because the function actually clears all the other non-changing points added by the add_points function. By the way, do you know where I can find the documentation for libigl because I can't find anything besides the tutorial? I can't even find this example that you showed here. I would like to learn a bit more like what that set_face_based is doing (and it seems like the is_animating is deprecated because the line is giving me error?).